# WordPress changing themes leaving previous tags

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I recently updated my theme (testing) and noticed that my posts have tags from the previous theme. Example `[foundry_image_carousel]` since the last theme was Foundry.

Is there an easy way to update the tags to remove them or update them so that new  image carousel replaces Foundry's?

Thank you

Comment: tags are part of the database, not the theme. Just like your posts don't get deleted when you change a theme, neither do your tags.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I did figure it out. Thank you!